# Is this passage from the textbook Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach incorrect?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, planning

On page 383, section 10.2. of the *Algorithms for Planning as State Space Search* chapter of the textbook *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach*, the following passage appears:

[image]

In this passage, the authors write that in the air cargo example they use there are $50^{10} \times 200^{50+10} \approx  10^{155}$ states.

Is this incorrect? Shouldn't there be $10^{50} \times 60^{200}$ states?

As far as my understanding of probability goes, there is a different state for all the different arrangements of the 50 planes, which can each be at one of 10 airports, which would give the result $10 \times 10 \times ... = 10^{50}$, and then the same reasoning applied to the placement of the packages on an airplane or at an airport gives $60 \times 60 \times ... = 60^{200}$, which together give  $10^{50} \times 60^{200}$.

Is the textbook incorrect or is my reasoning incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You are right.  That looks like an error in the textbook.  Check their [errata](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/errata.html), or send the authors a note to let them know.

Comment: There used to be a Google Drive document linked from the errata form, which had many more errors than the errata page. But it's no longer there.

Comment: I just sent the authors a note. Thanks for the suggestion.